# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'center'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I new to this and I tried to look through similar errors, but I am unsure why 'center' would be targeted as it centers the graph.

```
import yt

ds = yt.load("puredef_hdf5_chk_000000")
p = yt.ProjectionPlot(ds,'particle_postion_x', 'particle_postion_y',['particle_dens'], center='m', width=(20, 'Mpc'))
p.annotate_particles((20, 'Mpc'))
p.save()
```

With the output being:

```
runfile('C:/Users/rocke/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/home/richard/untitled7.py', wdir='C:/Users/rocke/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/home/richard')
yt : [WARNING  ] 2020-07-02 15:22:54,470 Extending theta dimension to 2PI + left edge.
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-02 15:22:54,484 Parameters: current_time              = 0.0
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-02 15:22:54,485 Parameters: domain_dimensions         = [2 2 0]
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-02 15:22:54,486 Parameters: domain_left_edge          = [ 0.0000e+00 -6.5536e+09  0.0000e+00]
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-02 15:22:54,487 Parameters: domain_right_edge         = [6.55360000e+09 6.55360000e+09 6.28318531e+00]
yt : [INFO     ] 2020-07-02 15:22:54,488 Parameters: cosmological_simulation   = 0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\rocke\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\richard\untitled7.py", line 12, in <module>
    p = yt.ProjectionPlot(ds,'particle_postion_x', 'particle_postion_y',['particle_dens'], center='m', width=(20, 'Mpc'))

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'center'
```

Comment: Please add what Python module you are using and version.

Comment: I thought  I already did when I put:

import yt

Comment: This assumes there is only one yt, it is better to be explicit about where things are coming from.  Adding the [yt] tag would help also. At the same time you would include information on the version so folks can get on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

The function `yt.ProjectionPlot` takes 3 parameters and the rest are optional parameters with a keyword. You are using 4 parameters, so 1 to many (`['particle_dens']`). That probably also needs to be a keyword parameter.

Documentation for the function:
https://yt-project.org/doc/reference/api/yt.visualization.plot_window.html#yt.visualization.plot_window.ProjectionPlot

Comment: I read through the article link you sent me and I have a question about creating two 'yt.ProjectionPlot'  that mesh, seeing how I am trying to get both the x and y particle position, and the density is needed for both the positions.

Comment: Maybe this links can help you: https://yt-project.org/doc/cookbook/simple_plots.html#simple-particle-plot, https://yt-project.org/doc/visualizing/plots.html#particle-plots. I am not familiar with this module, so I dont think that I can help you further.